# Print the last occurrence of a word in a TXT in Python

Tags: python-3.x, data-extraction

I'm working on extracting data from a .txt file, and I want to pick up the last occurrence of a certain word in the whole file. In this case, I get three occurrences of the words `D / DÑA` and `Tfno` but I want only the last one of each one and print it.

```py
def extract(in_filename):
    if not os.path.exists(in_filename):
        print("ERROR: Input file does not exist ❌ ")
        sys.exit()

    with open(in_filename, 'r') as file:
        rows = file.readlines()
        for row in rows:
            if re.match('D/DÑA', row):
                row_parse = row.strip()          

                print(row_parse)
            elif re.match('Tfno', row):
                row_parse = row.strip()          

                print(row_parse)


extract('apd29.txt')
```

The output is:

```
D/DÑA: PRUEBA PRUEBITA
Tfno: 666666666
D/DÑA: PRUEBA PRUEBITA
Tfno: 666666666
D/DÑA: PRUEBA PRUEBITA <-- I need this
Tfno: 666666666 <-- I need this
```

I expect the output:

```
D/DÑA: PRUEBA PRUEBITA
Tfno: 666666666
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `reversed`

**Ex:**

```
def extract(in_filename):
    if not os.path.exists(in_filename):
        print("ERROR: Input file does not exist ❌ ")
        sys.exit()

    with open(in_filename, 'r') as file:
        rows = file.readlines()
        for row in reversed(rows):      #!Update
            if re.match(r'D/DÑA', row):
                row_parse = row.strip()          

                print(row_parse)
                break


extract('apd29.txt')
```

Comment: Yes, it is work, thank you! But in my case, 'break' does not work if I want to search several words with the same procedure, for example, 'D / DÑA', 'Tfno' and 'F.N.' with if...elif..elif, with 'break' only print the last word of three, in this case, only the last ocurrence of 'Tfno'

Comment: Elegant! :D Good job.

Comment: @ozzrocker95. You need to change the logic then to replace `break` with removing the search word after each find...

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a variable outside of for loop would work in this situation.

```
result = "not found"    
with open(in_filename, 'r') as file:
    rows = file.readlines()
    for row in rows:
        if re.match('D/DÑA', row):
            row_strip = row.strip()
            row_parse = row_strip.rfind('D/DÑA')

            result = row_parse

print(result)
```